# Square SDK integration in Android issue on fragment

Tags: android, sdk, square

When I initialize  the Square SDK on fragment, it working fine but I am not getting callback data `onActivityResult`. The `onActivityResult` however is never hit. I've set breakpoints, but nothing is triggered. Can a fragment have onActivityResult? I'd think so since it's a provided function. Why isn't this being triggered?

```
  btn_pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //onPayWithCardClickListener.run();
            CardEntry.startCardEntryActivity(getActivity(), true,
                    DEFAULT_CARD_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE);
            
            }
    });

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   
    CardEntry.handleActivityResult(data, result -> {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            CardDetails cardResult = result.getSuccessValue();
            Card card = cardResult.getCard();
            String nonce = cardResult.getNonce();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Payment Success",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else if (result.isCanceled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Canceled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using both the old and new activity result APIs which doesn't make sense. Read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts) for how to get a result using the new API.